# Make a multilingual application in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, globalization, app-globalresources

I created an MVC web application using asp.net and visual studio 2012.

Now, I want to make it multilangual. Depending on the browsers language of the user, to open the page in one language or an other automatically.

I was searching on the internet and I create two global resources called:

```
ContentEN.resx
ContentES.resx
```

In both files I added some values with the same key and different value for example:

> Name: userInformation, value: User information
>   Name: userInformation, value: Informacion de usuario

Then on the HTML Im able to use the label like `@Resources.ContentES.UserInformation`

The problem is that I want to do it automatically. So the question is: once I create both files for both languages, how can I do use one or the other depending of the user's browser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name your resources differently:

```
Content.resx
Content.EN.resx
Content.ES.resx
```

Where Content.resx is the default fallback. And then request them like this:

```
@Resources.Content.UserInformation
```

But this only works if your thread language is set accordingly.

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Mar/27/Auto-Selecting-Cultures-for-Localization-in-ASPNET

The main point is this:

```
  <system.web>
    <globalization culture="auto:en-US" uiCulture="fr" />
  </system.web>
```